# BroadCast Receiver automatically stops

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am using the Broadcast Receiver in android application in API level 8, which is executed after every 10 minutes for this purpose I have used AlarmManager inside the broadcastReceiver which makes the execution continuously, but I check the receiver stops working after 1 day, But I checked in the KitKat it work perfectly without any issue. So please let me know is there any API issue or I have to use other way. Please share your view. Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us which API is working and which is not working you using

Comment: In API level 8 (Froyo) it stops after some time (one day) and It works in API level 19 (KitKat).